# How does the SUMIFS function compare strings with each other and why does the following not work?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was wondering what the problem is in Excel if I execute a `SUMIFS`. First place in J7 and J8 the following values: `'17168850000110001` and `'17168850000110000` respectively. Now place the values in column K7 and K8, the following values: `95` and `85`. If you set it up as follows, you should get the following table:

[image: Template]

Next, put in a cell, the following formula:

```
=SUMIFS($K$7:$K$8;$J$7:$J$8;J7)
```

This should return the value of `95`, but it returns a value of `180` in my Excel. Is it that my Excel is "broken"?

[image: Display]

[image: Formulas]

Comment: i get the same result, interesting its only when i change '17168850000110001 to '171688500001100100 does it work

Comment: This does not seem to work with texts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **tldr;** [SUMIFS](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumifs-function-c9e748f5-7ea7-455d-9406-611cebce642b) trades a wide variety of functionality in its criteria in exchange for failure in a very small and select set of circumstances.

---

Excel's SUMIFS is trying to interpret the 'text-that-looks-like-a-number' as numbers within the [15 significant digit limitation](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2008/04/10/understanding-floating-point-precision-aka-why-does-excel-give-me-seemingly-wrong-answers/). Within that limitation, they both look like `171688500001100<the rest doesn't matter>`.

If you change the values to something that cannot be interpreted as a number (e.g. `A17168850000110000` and `A17168850000110001`) then you get the correct result.

SUMIFS's text-to-number interpretation is why strings like `">="&10`or `"<"&TODAY()` work as criteria. This seems to be some form of Excel's native [Application.Evaluate method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.evaluate)¹ that takes 'strings-that-look-like-equations' and resolves them to a result. It vastly increases SUMIF and SUMIFS functionality but there are rogue cases (such as yours) when it backfires.

In order to achieve a pseudo-SUMIFS with your data, you need a worksheet function  that makes a literal comparison, not an interpreted one. SUMPRODUCT will do that.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((J$7:J$8=J7)*(K$7:K$8))
```

---

¹ <sub>I've used the Application.Evaluate method myself when developing a TEXTJOINIFS UDF.</sub>